# Images take a lot of time to load in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, struts2, batch-processing

I have a scenario where I am fetching multiple images from the Oracle database through the loop. But it's taking a lot of time to fetch the images and display it on the browser.
Through, this code I am calling my method with some parameters.

```
for(Object[] obj: memberDetails)
{
    System.out.println("String.valueOf(obj[0])"+String.valueOf(obj[0]));

    try{
        memberImage=dtSrvc.getQueImageForQC(Id,String.valueOf(obj[0]));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}

    map.put("memImage"+count, memberImage);
    key.add("memImage"+count);
    hmap.put("memImage"+count, memberImage);
    count++;
}
```

and here is my query through which I am fetching images

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("select photo from member_photo where ID='"
                        + Id + "' and que_id=" + QueId);
```

Please, let me know how can I speed up this process.
I am unable to fetch all images if the network is slow. My application is currently used by many peoples.

Comment: 1) I'm really skeptic about this being your bottleneck 2) _don't_ use arbitrary strings in your query - use parameters instead (`where ID = ? and que_id = ?` + `ps.setString(1, id); ps.setString(2, queId);`)

Comment: Is this solve my problem?

Comment: Don't use javascript to show your images, javascript is very slow.

Comment: No I am not using javascript for it.

Comment: Why do you need a second parameter in query? Isn't `ID` a primary key?

Comment: I have to use both the id to fetch the images from the table

Comment: Does your query perform well?

Comment: yes it working fine. I get all the images when i refresh the page second time

Comment: Are you using a proxy in the browser?

Comment: No I am not using proxy

Comment: Why do you sysout the image to the console? It slows down execution.

Comment: sure I will delete it and check the performance on the server. any other thing which I have to keep in mind for faster execution

Comment: A lot of them you should have in mind. What is a type of image, i.e. BLOB or CLOB?

Comment: Type of image is Clob

Comment: What is `getQueImageForQC` source code? Can't you just use `obj[0]` parameter?

Comment: `getQueImageForQC` is my method name where I have written sql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use individual query to fetch each image from the db. It makes a network overhead. You can try many of the solutions described here to change your code to do one query instead of many. See how to [Batching Select Statements in JDBC](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/batching.html).

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("select photo from member_photo where ID in (" + inClause.toString() + ')');
```

you don't need `que_id` if `ID` is a primary key in the table.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is about fetching images first and keep them as pure file(temp) on a accessible and public folder of your application, and then simply point them out with simple image resource using `img` tag.
The process would be like this.
`1.` Query images and keep them under `/a_public_folder/images/...` which each images is going be named as `1.jpeg`, `2.jpeg` where 1 and 2 are ids(unique).
`2.` keep the ids retrieved from the database with a simple context such as `list_id:List<Long>`
`3.` your final servlet would be like the following

```
for(long idx:list_id){
  out.print("<img src=\"/a_public_folder/images/"+idx+".jpeg\"/>");
}
```

`4.`you may also apply a filter for `/a_public_folder/images/*` path in order to just allow users who have permission to view content/images
`5.`have a session listener in order to remove associated(fetched) images to the particular user session, or have a daemon thread for cleaning up the directory(images have no links longer) interval.

But I suggest extract images from database to simple pure file and just keep the images path into the database.