# Preventing PreparedStatement from Clearing Batch in Java JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, batch-processing

I am working on a Java application where I need to execute a batch of SQL queries using JDBC's PreparedStatement. I have encountered an issue where the PreparedStatement seems to clear the batch every time it is initialized with a new query. Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```java
@Transactional
public int[] executeBatchQuery(String code, List<String> queries, List<List<String>> parametersList) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> errorMap = new HashMap<>();
    int[] count = {};

    if (queries.size() != parametersList.size()) {
        logger.info("Both lists length is not equal");
        return null;
    }

    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnectionByCode(code);

        for (int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
            String query = queries.get(i);
            List<String> parameters = parametersList.get(i);

            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);

            // Set parameters for the prepared statement
            for (int j = 0; j < parameters.size(); j++) {
                pstmt.setString(j + 1, parameters.get(j));
            }

            pstmt.addBatch();
        }

        if (pstmt != null) {
            count = pstmt.executeBatch();
        }
        else {
            throw new SQLException();
        }
    }

    catch (SQLException exception) {
        logger.info("Roll back successfully executed");
        logger.info("printing StackTrace: ");
        exception.printStackTrace();

        errorMap.put("mBoolean", "true");
        errorMap.put("errorMessage", exception.getMessage());
    }

    finally {
        try {
            if (pstmt != null) {
                pstmt.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

> In the list of queries, each query is different, with varying columns, WHERE clauses, and sometimes different tables

I have noticed that every time I initialize the PreparedStatement with a new query, it clears the batch. This behavior is not desirable for my application, as I need to execute multiple queries in a batch. Can someone suggest a workaround or an alternative approach to prevent the PreparedStatement from clearing the batch every time it is initialized with a new query?

I attempted to execute a batch of SQL queries using JDBC's PreparedStatement in a Java application. The goal was to add multiple queries to the batch and execute them together for efficiency.

Specifically, I initialized a PreparedStatement object and iterated through a list of queries, adding each query to the batch using the addBatch() method. I then expected the PreparedStatement to retain all the queries in the batch, allowing me to execute them in one go.

However, despite adding multiple queries to the batch, I observed that only the last query added to the batch was being executed. It seems that each time the PreparedStatement was initialized with a new query, it cleared the batch, resulting in only the latest query being executed.

I expected all the queries in the batch to be executed sequentially, but this was not the case. Instead, only the last query in the batch was executed, disregarding the previous queries.

Comment: Using addBatch only makes sense if you are re-using the statement. You have a loop of `queries.size()` which wipes the previous value of `pstmt` and so only execute the very last `PreparedStatement`, and never call `addBatch` a second time for any statement.

Comment: It is not clear how did you use this function. Do you have any test cases? Where did you see a clearance of the batch statement? You should provide more information for the overview. Currently it is only a poorly written code with bugs that you didn't try to resolve.

Comment: Thank you for your input @DuncG. While I've successfully used simple statements for batch execution, I'm encountering challenges with PreparedStatements. I'm currently seeking alternative approaches or insights into executing batch queries with PreparedStatements while accommodating different SQL statements and parameter values. Any suggestions or pointers to resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RomanC I recognize the need for clarity in the function's functionality. It executes SQL queries with parameters, and I aim to execute multiple queries in a batch using prepared statements. The function handles parameterized queries well, but I seek help with batch logic. Your insights would greatly aid my refinement efforts. Additionally, please note that the queries and parameters are generated dynamically at runtime, which makes it challenging to provide specific examples.

Comment: @Mubashir This is errorneus approach you want to add a new functionality to the working code. Because you have to rewrite the code from scratch to make a new logic. Modifying existed code will break the function will no longer work. Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27273227/573032) answer could give you an idea how to use batch statement.